# Access files located in the WIP folder of BIM360 Design (old C4R)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

We have a requirement from one of our clients to access the **project files** that are stored in the **BIM360 Design** (old Collaboration for Revit - C4R). I can not find any information in the developer pages of the Forge APIs that points to this location. I assume such an API is not part of Forge, but we were wondering if there is any other API that can provide those files.
The exact requirements are:

- Constantly **monitor** for changes on the files located there.
- When changes occur, retrieve and **backup** all those files to a local machine.

The question is, *how, if possible, can we access the project files located at the BIM360 Design cloud*?

---

**UPDATE** *(10/04/2018)*

We have found [these commands](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/commands/) - specifically `PublishModel` and `GetPublishModelJob`. This does something, we can at the very least prompt the publication on demand, without the need for Revit. It is not clear to me **when** the `items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel` pseudo-file is created. On top of that, the API does not appear to be able to receive a prefered output folder, which makes it really cumbersome to work for the intended purpose of backing up the information inside BIM360 Design.

**UPDATE** *(25/04/2018)*

We have tried using both commands (`PublishJob` and `GetPublishModelJob`). We have impersonated a Project Admin (via the `x-user-id`) but Forge is returning a 401 error (which is not even documented). The following (with a redacted documentID) is what we have tried:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
      "version": "1.0"
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "commands",
      "attributes": {
        "extension": {
          "type": "commands:autodesk.bim360:C4RModelGetPublishJob",
          "version": "1.0.0"
      }
    },
    "relationships": {
      "resources": {
        "data": [ { "type": "items", "id": "<document_id>" } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is Forge's response:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "a4547153-1fd4-4710-b0d1-a7184d9e7e22",
            "status": "401",
            "code": "C4R",
            "detail": "Failed to get publish model job"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: As I remember, you must have to push models from C4R before accessing it via Forge API. But I'm not 100% sure, please hold on, I'm checking with our engineering team.

Comment: What is the `items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel pseudo-file` you mentioned? Did you mean the extension type of the item data shown in Forge DM API reposne, such as [GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) or [GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/)
 ?

Comment: If the `items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel pseudo-file` you mentioned is what I mean above, Revit C4R extenstion will create a `items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel` item for that model and publish 1st version in Docs folder you specified after initializing collaboration with my quick test.

Comment: @EasonKang Yes, I mean that extension type from the `/contents` folder exploration. And OK, it works how I supposed it worked, which is C4R creates the file as soon as the collaboration is set up, well before the first export. Correct me if I'm wrong. Nonetheless, the issue of accessing such file and making it export to another location still persists.

Comment: @frascaroli Yes, the item with `items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel` extension type will be created as soon as the collaboration is set up. After that, there will be two versions of the item will the created at least with my observation.

Comment: Is the answer above clear enough for you?

Comment: @EasonKang I have updated the answer, can you please check if either you or Augusto know the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @frascaroli The token must have these two scopes `data:create data:write`

Comment: If you do include these two scope in your token, but it's still reporting error like you mentioned. Please send your item urn with the `urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage` prefix and the error response to forge.help[AT]autodesk DOT com

Comment: Yes, we have enabled every scope, for reference `account:read account:write data:read data:write data:create code:all`. I will do what you ask, thanks!

Comment: I may be repeating something already suggested as the thread is getting long. stepping back a bit - do you have an access right to the workshared Revit file? Publish command is to publish workshared central model in the cloud to Docs. to use it, you need an access to Revit file. Publish command does the same thing as publish command in Revit. to use cloud workshared feature, first you need to have an license, then you also need to be a member a revit project.  (a bit complicated, I know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with @tfrascaroli in Forge Help channel, we found the root cause of this error is caused by the incorrect value of `x-user-id`, so he didn't have the right permission to push the latest version of the C4R model to BIM360 docs.

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "a4547153-1fd4-4710-b0d1-a7184d9e7e22",
            "status": "401",
            "code": "C4R",
            "detail": "Failed to get publish model job"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `x-user-id` is not a GUID and not the `id` we saw in the response of [GET users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/) or [GET users/:user_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-:user_id-GET/), it should be the value of the `uid`. After replacing the `x-user-id` value by the `uid`, the error doesn't show up again.

```
[
  {
    "id": "a75e8769-621e-40b6-a524-0cffdd2f784e",  //!<<< We didn't use it for `x-user-id`
    "account_id": "9dbb160e-b904-458b-bc5c-ed184687592d",
    "status": "active",
    "role": "account_admin",
    "company_id": "28e4e819-8ab2-432c-b3fb-3a94b53a91cd",
    "company_name": "Autodesk",
    "last_sign_in": "2016-04-05T07:27:20.858Z",
    "email": "john.smith@mail.com",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "nickname": "Johnny",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "uid": "L9EBJKCGCXBB",   //!<<<<< Here is the value for the x-user-id
    "image_url": "http://static-dc.autodesk.net/etc/designs/v201412151200/autodesk/adsk-design/images/autodesk_header_logo_140x23.png",
    "address_line_1": "The Fifth Avenue",
    "address_line_2": "#301",
    "city": "New York",
    "postal_code": "10011",
    "state_or_province": "New York",
    "country": "United States",
    "phone": "(634)329-2353",
    "company": "Autodesk",
    "job_title": "Software Developer",
    "industry": "IT",
    "about_me": "Nothing here",
    "created_at": "2015-06-26T14:47:39.458Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-04-07T07:15:29.261Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. When creating a project with Forge's API one must use the user's `id`, and that was the source of confusion. But when dealing with these commands you MUST use, as Eason states, the user's `uid`, and that user MUST have access to the BIM360 Dessign (aka C4R) model.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an access right to the workshared Revit file? Publish command is to publish workshared central model in the cloud to Docs. To use it, you need an access to Revit model in the central in the cloud. Forge Publish command does the same thing as publish command in Revit desktop. You need the same access right. To use cloud workshared feature, first you need to have Design license assigned to you, then you also need to be a member a Revit project. Being invited to Docs is not enough.

(As C4R/Design was merged to Docs recently, this C4R specific license part was intentionally kept the same as previous licensing. We also have Team for earlier versions. It makes it a bit complicated. I hope it will be easier as we move forward in future.)

Comment: Thank you for your input. It appears the problem was indeed caused by a lack of permission, but also because we were using the user's ID instead of the UID for the impersonation. I've asked Eason to write what he told me over e-mail as an answer so I can accept it. Else I'll wirte it myself for everyone else.